# JBoss EJBLocal LookUp failed - JBAS011857: NamingStore is null

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss6.x

We are running application in JBoss EAP 6.4 with java 1.7, Everything worked until restart our server.
After restart it was not started correctly and started showing **JBAS011857: NamingStore is null** error whenever application trying to communicate with database.

After some time restarted the same instance again, luckily its started working fine. Is there any issue with JBoss EAP6.4 any one faced this issue before?

```
(ajp-/0.0.0.0:8009-1278) [anonymous:506728-2019051522072159282795@102.115.150.130] [EJBLookUpUtil][getProcessTransactionEJBLocal] [Error in getProcessTransactionEJBLocal LookUp]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS011857: NamingStore is null
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.<init>(NamingContext.java:152)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.<init>(NamingContext.java:125)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:117)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.mobeix.gateway.web.servlets.MxGZipServletFilter.doFilter(MxGZipServletFilter.java:57) [mobeix.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:91)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.17.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.17.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:490) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:422) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.24.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.24.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
```